# iOS7 to iOS8 application files migration

Tags: ios, ios7, filesystems, migration, ios8

I am currently testing my app on iOS8. Everything works well on pure iOS8 but I am struggling with the App files migration from iOS7 that will occur for users when iOS8 will be publicly released. As my application uses several "Standard Directories" (Documents, Application Support, ...), I would like to be sure the migration will be smooth.

The application filesystem structure has changed on iOS8 (read [iOS beta 4 Release note](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.0/) and the [file system programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3)).

When iOS8 will be installed on a device, I guess all previously installed applications and all related files (in Documents, Application Support, ...) will be re-organized to match the new structure.

Do you guys have any clues about the (exhaustive) list of changes that will occur during iOS7 to iOS8 upgrade ? I can't find any documentation on this subject.
Is there a way to test/simulate a migration of an iOS7 application sandbox to the new iOS8 sandbox structure ?

Thanks

BONUS question: does the application GUID change when the OS upgrades ?

Comment: If you're using NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains function or the URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error: methods to access your directories, you should be fine. Apple recommends you use these methods to access directories.

Comment: Also, if you're not sure, download Xcode 6 beta and test it in the iOS 8 simulator.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The file system layout of app containers has changed on disk.
>
> Rather
>   than relying on hard-coded directory structure, use the
>   `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` function or the
>   `URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:` method of the
>   `NSFileManager` class.

Using the `URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:` method of `NSFileManager`:

```
NSFileManager *yourFileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *urlForSomeDirectory = [yourFileManager URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSAllDomainsMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:nil];
```

***If you are currently using this method, then you don't need to change a thing.***

You can replace `NSDocumentDirectory` with [many other constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSSearchPathDirectory). You may also want to substitute a `NSError **` for the last parameter if you would like to catch an error.

The bonus question: It shouldn't, however you never know.

Comment: Indeed, I use the NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains function, but I rely at some point on the pre-iOS8 filesystem structure, and used somewhere a relative path... Thanks you for the bonus answer, I wish I could give you a bonus point!