# Xcode 6/iOS 8 - Where is the .app file

Tags: ios8, xcode6, .app

Whilst developing apps for iOS which utilise Core Data, I use the Core Data Editor application for debugging purposes. To do this Core Data Editor requires the application containing the managed object model.

To get the .app file I locate the application locally (if running on the simulator) or on the device using iExplorer.

Now, as of Xcode 6/iOS 8 the .app file no longer appears for some reason.

Here is a screenshot of a test project run on the iOS 7 simulator (using Xcode 6):

[image: Screenshot showing .app file from iOS 7 simulator]

Now, as you can see the Test.app file is where it should be, however if I run the same project using the iOS 8 simulator, the file does not exist:

[image: Screenshot showing NO .app file from iOS 8 simulator]

Does anyone have any idea why the .app file is no longer shown for iOS 8 projects? This happens on both the iOS 8 simulator and an iOS 8 device.

Comment: iOS 8 now uses different directory structure. Frankly said, it even appears less friendly. I am not sure about your app design, but you may want to know that the .app is now located within `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<device-specific-hash>/data/Containers/Bundle/<app-specific-hash>` in case of Simulator.

Comment: @lef thanks for that, I can now see the .app file from the simulator. Do you by any chance know why this has disappeared from apps on an actual device running iOS 8?

Comment: Not sure, the structure has simply changed. Authors of iExplorer now should rely on new APIs to provide access to the .app packages, as also mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/a/24936304